# Проверка на уникальность Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, валидация, entity-framework

Никак не могу сформулировать. Как организовать проверку данных на уникальность в `Entity framework` с возможностью отображения ошибки через `Validation.ErrorTemplate`. Или это уже делается на уровне элемента управления + `ValidationRule`?

Comment: Я не пробовал сам, но в интернете советуют перекрыть `ValidateEntity` в `DbContext`. Не знаю, поможет ли это для валидации на лету.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте отдельный сервис, управляющий загрузкой и сохранением Ваших доменных сущностей.
В этом сервисе проверяйте данные на уникальность перед сохранением.
Если же Вам необходимо получить дубликаты, поступайте совершенно таким же образом.